# uploadify freezing on ie midway through upload

Tags: javascript, flash, uploadify

I've been making an uploadify / jCrop library for CI, where users can upload pics, then crop them in a pop up window, nice and easily.

It works lovely, but I've noticed on IE the upload will stop midway through uploading, not at the same place every time, freeze for a while and then I'm hit with an IO error.

It's a pesky problem, and the script works fine in all other browsers I have tested (safari, chrome, ff).

Could you have a look, and let me know if you have any ideas as to what's going on?

http://reallywebdesign.com/uploadify_max

Thanks

Comment: are you using authorization (cookies) or SSL. booth make some trouble in uploadify and different browser.

Comment: It's not SSL. If you take a look at the link you can see how it's running. Thanks.

Comment: It worked for me in IE8 with an 1 MB image. But as a note, if your library is included into a CMS which uses authentication and the upload also requires authentication by server side there may be problems with uploadify if you do not send the auth information manually.

Comment: Hey Daniel. Thanks for trying. I've updated to the latest flash on my testing PC and it works for me too now. Although I don't trust it all that much!

Comment: And yes, I'm working with a good uploadify patch for CI to overcome the session problems. If anyone else has trouble uploading through IE with this script, it would be great to know.

Comment: I am having the same or a similar issue, terminating with an IO::Error #2038.  Interestingly, the upload fails only on my remote server for file > ~400K.  I think it may be related to the number of progress updates?  I am using asp.net and a work around for the AUTH cookie issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Worked OK here in IE9 with a > 1MB file. When I was debugging Uploadify problems in my project I ended up using Wireshark on my computer and filtering for the `ip.addr` I was uploading too and setting protocol to HTTP. It helped me see the actual HTTP / error of the content displayed since this information doesn't get piped back to Uploadify in full.